# Using dot notation for custom classes

Tags: objective-c

I've always wondered about this.

I have an `@property` called hitCounter and this works fine:

`if ([[someArray objectAtIndex:i] hitCounter]!=0) continue;`

No problem, it works. There is no getter method `hitCounter` that I wrote; it is there because of the `@synthesize` right?

However, properties are supposed to allow for dot notation. Even though the property exists, is synthesized, and the class header for the objects in this array is imported, neither of the following compiles:

`if ([someArray objectAtIndex:i].hitCounter!=0) continue;`

or

`if ((MyClass*)[someArray objectAtIndex:i].hitCounter!=0) continue;`

The compiler says `property hitCounter not found on object of type id` but clearly I am casting it to `MyClass` so it should not longer be type `id` -- what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put `(MyClass*)[someArray objectAtIndex:i]` inside parentheses:

```
if (((MyClass*)[someArray objectAtIndex:i]).hitCounter!=0) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The compiler says property hitCounter not found on object of type id
>   but clearly I am casting it to MyClass so it should not longer be type
>   id -- what is going on here?

This is just an operator precedence issue. You're casting the result of the entire expression `[someArray objectAtIndex:i].hitCounter` to `MyClass*`, but you're expecting the cast to apply just to `[someArray objectAtIndex:i]`. Use parentheses to rectify the situation, as shown in sch's answer.